# Integration by parts in Sobolev space

Tags: integration, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I'm looking for a reference of the following fact (if it is true...): if $u\in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ and $v \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ ($\Omega$ a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \ge 1$) with a regular boundary, one may suppose first that $\Omega$ is bounded) then we have
$$
\int_\Omega \partial_{x_i} u v + \int_\Omega u \partial_{x_i} v = \int_{\partial \Omega} u v n_i
$$
where $n_i$ is the $i$-th component of the exterior normal of $\Omega$.
The same result is true when $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $v \in W^{1,q}(\Omega)$ with $1< p < \infty$ and $q$ is such that $1/p+1/q=1$ but I can't find a proof in this case.

Comment: If your $\Omega$ is bounded then it is definitely hold. But for unbounded $\Omega$, I don't know. Because we only talk about Gauss-Green theorem in bounded domain, even if for smooth function.

Comment: @wisher Can you provide a reference for the case $\Omega$ bounded?

Comment: You can find this in Evans & Gariepy

Comment: @wisher Can you tell me more exactly where? I can't find it.

Comment: Chapter 4, look for trace operator

Comment: @wisher In the section 4.3 (about traces of Sobolev functions) of this book, they only consider the space $W^{1,p}$ with $1\le p <\infty$. So the case of $W^{1,\infty}$ isn't included here.

Comment: For infinite space, you have lipschitz functions and hence the classical green theory hold

Comment: @wisher And where can I find this theory developed for Lipschitz functions? And the fact that $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) \subset C^{0,1}(\bar{\Omega})$?

Comment: Please check out section 4.2.3 at page 131 for lipschitz functions...